# How to rreset accelerometer event [As3]

Tags: actionscript-3

In my project I need to access my Background Image to run continuously. As of now I have done it but it is smooth in SWF and apk is very slow. Is there any other solution please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset Accelerometer Event As3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523848/how-to-reset-accelerometer-event-as3)

Comment: Your question title and question body don't seem to relate to each other.  Is your question about performance or the accelerometer events?

Comment: Show your code of how you are rotating the image, and advise what type of object your image is.  eg.  Vector/Shape,  Bitmap (what size).

Comment: My problem is about accelerometer event and my image is Bitmap of size 74 * 84. Any more additional details needed other than this

Answer (score 0):

go to `Edit Application Settings` and try to set `Render Mode` to `GPU`.

Comment: then try to not use vectors image or low compressed bitmaps. You have the option to compress bitmaps in Public Settings  JPEG Quallity. try this.